# How to make Javascript filter value based on dynamic key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, javascript-objects

I have one record and need to filter it according to supplied key and keep to another array. So normally  we do like this..

```
let date = [];
date.push(data.filter(e => e.date).map(e => e.date));
```

this will give me data of`['2020-09-12','2020-09-12','2020-09-12','2020-09-12']` in new date array.So now I have requirement to filter out dynamic key to new array.It is based on Daily, Weekly, Monthly which will look like this..(doing manually right now..)

if user select **daily** data..

```
let newArray30, newArray20, newArray10= [];
newArray30.push(data.filter(e => e.d_dy_30).map(e => e.d_dy_30));
newArray20.push(data.filter(e => e.d_dy_20).map(e => e.d_dy_20));
newArray10.push(data.filter(e => e.d_dy_10).map(e => e.d_dy_10));
```

if user select **weekly** data..

```
let newArray30, newArray20, newArray10= [];
newArray30.push(data.filter(e => e.d_wk_30).map(e => e.d_wk_30));
newArray20.push(data.filter(e => e.d_wk_20).map(e => e.d_wk_20));
newArray10.push(data.filter(e => e.d_wk_10).map(e => e.d_wk_10));
```

if user select **monthly** data..

```
let newArray30, newArray20, newArray10= [];
newArray30.push(data.filter(e => e.d_mt_30).map(e => e.d_mt_30));
newArray20.push(data.filter(e => e.d_mt_20).map(e => e.d_mt_20));
newArray10.push(data.filter(e => e.d_mt_10).map(e => e.d_mt_10));
```

and I will have 10 lines of each 'daily, weekly, monthly,quarterly,yearly'

I want to make it dynamic like this..

```
n30Data.push(data.filter(e =>e.this.getNaming(period,code)).map(e =>e.this.getNaming(period,code)))
//ofcourse this is error



  getNaming(period, code){

    return 'd'_'+period+'_'+code+'';
    
  }
```

how can I achieve something like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will filter the result based on dynamic `filterName` key:

```
function getNaming(period, code){

    return 'd_' + period + '_' + code;
    
  }

var filterName = getNaming(period,code);
n30Data.push(data.filter(e => e[filterName]).map(e => e[filterName])
```